# How to add pivot table filters with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, excel-interop

I create a pivot table based on an Excel (.xlsx) file. The program adds fields to rows, values, and the filter. Using PivotFilters.Add2 causes 0x800a03ec error which terminates the program. How to properly use `PivotFilters.Add2`?

I tried filtering on different fields with different data types. Also, I tried using `Type.Missing` in a place of unused arguments. There seems to be plenty of information of this method for VB, but not so much for C#.

Items selected in the filter should be between the two dates on the last line.

```
    var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlApp.Visible = true;
    var workBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(spreadsheetLocation);
    var workSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets["Data"];
    var workSheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets.Add();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range last = workSheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = workSheet1.get_Range("A1", last);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCaches pivotCaches = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCache pivotCache = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable pivotTable = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields pivotFields = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField filterField = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField accNumField = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField amountPaidField = null;

    pivotCaches = workBook.PivotCaches();
    pivotCache = pivotCaches.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, range);

    pivotTable = pivotCache.CreatePivotTable(workSheet2.Cells[1,1]);
    pivotFields = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields)pivotTable.PivotFields();
    amountPaidField = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField)pivotFields.Item("AmountPaid");
    amountPaidField.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
    amountPaidField.NumberFormat = "$#,###,###.00";

    accNumField = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField)pivotFields.Item("AccNumber");
    accNumField.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;

    filterField = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField)pivotFields.Item("AccDate");
    filterField.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
    filterField.EnableMultiplePageItems = true;
    filterField.PivotFilters.Add2(XlPivotFilterType.xlDateBetween, Type.Missing, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20));
```

Comment: If you try it manually, you'll see, that you can't add a filter to a page field (only to row or column fields). So you have to loop over its pivotitems and set their visibility. And you have to assure, that at least one pivotitem remains visible (you'll get an error if you try to set them all invisible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above by Asger, the filter can't be added to a page field. Instead, the pivot item's visibility property has to be set.

```
var pivotItems = filterField.PivotItems();
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Name);
foreach (var item in pivotItems)
{
    item.Visible = false;
    if (date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) || date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20))
    {
        item.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well answered, but keep in mind: At least one pivotitem has to remain visible (you can not disable all pivoitems of a pagefield). Worst case: If only the last pivotitem of your loop fulfils the condition, then you set it to `Visible = false` directly before ... and get an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
  #First it deletes two rows and then it creates a pivot table#
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    
    
    namespace ConsoleApplication4
    {
        class Program
        {
            public static string Column(int column)
            {
                column--;
                if (column >= 0 && column < 26)
                    return ((char)('A' + column)).ToString();
                else if (column > 25)
                    return Column(column / 26) + Column(column % 26 + 1);
                else
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Column #" + (column + 1).ToString());
            }
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
    
            {
               
    
                try
                {
                    string path = @"C:\Users\UX155512\Documents\Book1fd.xlsx";
                    var excelFile = new Application();
                    Workbook workBook = excelFile.Workbooks.Open(path);
                    Worksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheets[1];
                    Worksheet pivotSheet = workBook.Worksheets.Add(
                        System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                        workBook.Worksheets[workBook.Worksheets.Count],
                        1,
                        System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    
    
    
    
                    Range last = workSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
                    int lastRow = last.Row;
                    int lastCol = last.Column;
                    string lastColVal = Column(lastCol);
                    string lastFilledCol = lastColVal + lastRow.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(lastFilledCol);
                    Console.WriteLine(lastColVal);
                  
                    Console.WriteLine(lastRow);
                    Console.WriteLine(lastCol);
    
                   
                    for (int i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++)
                    {
                        if (workSheet.Cells[1][i].Value == ("HDR"))
                        {
                            workSheet.Rows[i].Delete();
                            Console.WriteLine("The Row Containing HDR has been deleted");
                        }
                        if (workSheet.Cells[1][i].Value == ("TRL"))
                        {
                            workSheet.Rows[i].Delete();
                            Console.WriteLine("The Row Containing TLR has been deleted");
                        }
    
                    }
    
    
                   
                    Range lastRange = workSheet.Range["A1", lastFilledCol];
    
                    
    
                    
                    pivotSheet.Name = "Pivot Table";
                   
                    Range range = pivotSheet.Cells[1, 1];
                    PivotCache pivotCache = (PivotCache)workBook.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, lastRange);
                    PivotTable pivotTable = (PivotTable)pivotSheet.PivotTables().Add(PivotCache: pivotCache, TableDestination: range);
                    PivotField pivotField = (PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Plan Number");
                    pivotField.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    
                    PivotField pivotField2 = (PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Source");
                    pivotField2.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
    
                    PivotField pivotField3 = (PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Total");
                    pivotField3.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
                    pivotField3.Function = XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;
                   
    
                 
                    workBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\UX155512\Documents\Excel Dump\Trial9.xlsx");
                    workBook.Close();
                    
    
                   
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                   
                }
    
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find the answer to pretty much ANY interop question is to record a macro then examine the source.